# Retry a forkjoin call after one fails

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I need the data from each of the services in the array to return at the end of the forkjoin call so if one fails, I need it to try the calls again.

Let's say in the example below that one of the three items in the `requests` array fails.

```
request(): Observable<T> {
    const requests = [
      this.getService$.getOne(),
      this.getService$.getTwo(),
      this.getService$.getThree()
    ]

    return forkJoin(requests).pipe(
      map(res => this.formatFunc(res))
    );
  }
```

What should the code look like so that when `this.request()` is called, I still get the data from all three services even if one fails and has to get data again?

I did some digging and found that people were adding `this.getService$.getOne().catch(e => of([]))` ... but that only appears to return nothing, rather than make the call again.

I've also seen something like this using `retry`

```
forkJoin(requests).pipe(
      retry(3),
      map(res => this.formatFunc(res))
    )
```

But will retry redo all three calls or just the one that failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although answer above has invalid error handling, the idea is correct: you have to handle errors on each request apart. Should be done as follows:

```
forkJoin([
request1.pipe(retryWhen(genericRetryStrategy())),
request2.pipe(retryWhen(genericRetryStrategy()))
])
```

The `genericRetryStrategy` that was mentioned in the example, can be taken from here (as an example): https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html EXAMPLE 2: CUSTOMIZABLE RETRY WITH INCREASED DURATION.

You can provide instead of it any other logic you want

Answer (score 2):

Retry the individual requests

```js
const { forkJoin, of, throwError } = rxjs;
const { retry, tap } = rxjs.operators;

let retryCount = 0;

const requests = [
  of(1),
  of(2),
  throwError('thrown error').pipe(
    tap(
      val => { console.log(val); },
      error => {
        console.log(retryCount ? `Retry ${retryCount}:` : 'First:', error);
        retryCount++;
      }
    )
  )
];

forkJoin(requests.map(request => request.pipe(retry(3)))).subscribe(
  val => { console.log(val); },
  error => { console.log('Sub:', error); }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It certainly does. I just made a runable snippet to prove it does.

Comment: Since ```forkJoin``` fails, in subscribe you're not receiving the not error values.

Answer (score 1):

handle forkjoin with `mergemap`

```
import { of,forkJoin,throwError, } from 'rxjs';
import { retry,tap,mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

let r1=of([1,2,3]).pipe(tap(()=>console.log("r1 called ..."))),
    r2=of([4,5,6]).pipe(tap(()=>console.log("r2 called ..."))),
    r3=of([7,8,9]).pipe(tap(()=>console.log("r3 called ...")));

of({})
.pipe(
  mergeMap(
    ()=>forkJoin(r1,r2,r3,throwError("some error"))
  ),
  tap({
    next:()=>{
      console.log("next...")
    },
    error:()=>{
      console.log("error..");
    }
  }),
 retry(3)
).subscribe();
```

this should console `error` 4 times.

here is the link with playground [rxjs playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-playground-test)

Comment: This will serialise the requests rather than them happening in parallel.