# ForkJoin, repeat a specific observable call until desired value is retrieved before proceed with subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

I am using **ngrx store** selectors on start of my component to retrieve data from my storage, these data may change any time through **store dispatches** from web sockets.

I am using a **forkJoin** on start of my component to retrieve these data from the selectors and use them appropriately.

**Code example**

my-component.ts

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
   
    forkJoin([
        this.myNgrxStore.select(storeSelector1).pipe(take(1)),
        this.myNgrxStore.select(storeSelector2).pipe(take(1)),
        this.myNgrxStore.select(storeSelector3).pipe(take(1)),
    ]).subscribe(result => { 
        // proceed with data as result[0], result[1], result[2],
        // call randomMethod only if result[1] is equal to '50', 
        // else try retrieve value from the store again till it becomes
        this.randomMethod(result[0], result[1], result[2]);
    }
}
```

**However,** I want to proceed with my randomMethod in the subscription of forkJoin **only when specific value is returned from storeSelector2**, for example **only if response of storeSelector2 is equal to '50'**, if it is not, add a delay of (let's say 1000ms and retry retrieve that value).

What is the best approach to achieve my scenario? (I feel that there should be more than one). Thanks in advance

Comment: There's something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58828087/retry-a-forkjoin-call-after-one-fails)

Using RxJS [retryWhen](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retrywhen).

Comment: how about filtering the stream for a particular value that you are interested in?

Comment: @RiteshWaghela thank you follow up, if I understood correctly you propose to do something like the following 

`this.myNgrxStore.select(storeSelector2).pipe(
                filter((response) => response === 50), take(1)
            )`  ? Would something like that work?

Comment: @Laurence thanks for your answer, the retryWhen option seems very interesting

Comment: @NickAth Yes that should work imo. As forkjoin will emit once all of the observables have completed.

Comment: Or you can also map your response from forkJoin and check condition and return array when your desired value has arrived.

Answer (score 0):

An example using map:

```
const requestArray = [];
    requestArray.push(of(1));
    requestArray.push(of(2));
    requestArray.push(of(3));
    requestArray.push(of(4));

    forkJoin(requestArray).pipe(map(result => {
      if(result[1] === 2) {
        return result;
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    })).subscribe(result => {
      if(result.length) {
        // do what you want
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for your code example, unfortunately this does not fit for my case since what I want is  while `this.myNgrxStore.select(storeSelector2)`  returns response different than 50, retry `this.myNgrxStore.select(storeSelector2)` and when this is achieved, proceed with the forkJoin subscription, any idea for that?